# No sound, dummy output, realtek ac880, ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, sound

can someone help with this, I´ve tried a lot of web info but I am a little lost here.

Thanks

http://www.alsa-project.org/db/?f=2ae67679fedfaeeeafdb744ff591b5d09c1be35f

Comment: I have tried almost everything about sound troubleshooting on the web, install ALSA, re install pulse audio, install pavucontrol,also  everything posted here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/462655/lubuntu-14-04-no-soundcard-detected-hda-intel-realtek-alc880

Except, that I can`t install the realtek driver with the instructions given in the driver folder, and also in the link above.

I am running out of ideas, any clues will be appreciated.